# Qt 4.8 windows 7 how to show tablet pc input panel

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, keyboard, touch

I have a Qt application running on windows 7. I have of course some input area that I want to fill using a virtual keyboard because I have a touch screen monitor. Windows virtual keybord is called "tablet pc input panel" and when I touch, for example, this text area, it shows a tooltip to make the keyboard visible. How I can do the same in my Qt application?[image: tooltip]

Comment: This may give you the clue: https://forum.qt.io/topic/48577/qt5-com-interface-itextinputpanel-in-windows-doesn-t-work-while-fine-in-qt4-7-touch-event

Comment: this is very interesting. however, I cannot find how to include in my project ITextInputPanel class that he use

Comment: That guy uses COM and includes some definition file. You can try to include: Peninputpanel.h I would try to use Qt own import: TYPELIBS = $$PWD/dll/Tiptsf.dll but of course the code will be a bit different. That is from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695563(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you said, but compiler can't find Peninputpanel.h. I tried to include the path where that header is, but then I have a lot of error in windows.h header. I guess this is a problem because I use mingw to compile my project, but those header require vs compiler.

Comment: If you use your own import with TYPELIBS in .pro file then you don't use Peninputpanel.h (which I am not sure where to get). It is either normal C++/COM as in that example or Qt/COM which you need to explore.